# Installation Package Created Using Wix Launches Another Instance Of the Installer During Installation

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.7

I have created a WIX installation bundle that installs my application along with all of its dependencies. The installation works great until you run it on a clean install of Windows 10. On a clean install of Windows 10, after installing SQL Server, a new installation window (of the application I'm currently installing) appears. If I dismiss the window, everything installs fine, but if I click ok then

[Link to Text File with Bundle Code](https://btetechnologies-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/p/mroy/EdkvL6PdJdpKlv31Yoz4F3wBchojdlCK8R3yX6tKY52qwQ?e=TRofcL)

Comment: We will stay tuned for the rest... :-). Is this a setup.exe or an MSI file you kick off?

Comment: OK, should have read properly what was there - whilst waiting for the rest. It is a WiX bundle. We need to see the bundle source to know what you are installing and in what order and such things. Maybe you got it solved already?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul I updated the question with a link to the code within the bundle. I am not able to share the source and stack overflow could not handle the code. Hopefully this helps. Still running into this problem.